# cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to insert data into an Oracle database, while in the process I am getting this error `cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Python value of type tuple not supported.`

Script I am using

```
curs.execute('insert into APP(APP_CODE,APP_NAME,PARENT_APP_CODE,INSERT_DTTM,INSERT_USER,UPDATE_DTTM,UPDATE_USER,IDFED_PROVIDER_ID,IDFED_SAML_GTWY_URL,TEMPLATE_FTL,USER_ACCTS_FLAG,XML_DATA_FLAG,CAPS_REQUIRED,SESSIONID_REQUIRED) VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14)'',row_data)
```

DB Schema

```
(APP_CODE VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, APP_NAME VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, PARENT_APP_CODE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, INSERT_DTTM TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL 
, INSERT_USER VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) DEFAULT USER NOT NULL 
, UPDATE_DTTM TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL 
, UPDATE_USER VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) DEFAULT USER NOT NULL 
, IDFED_PROVIDER_ID VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) 
, IDFED_SAML_GTWY_URL VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) 
, TEMPLATE_FTL CLOB 
, USER_ACCTS_FLAG VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) 
, XML_DATA_FLAG VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) 
, CAPS_REQUIRED VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N' 
, SESSIONID_REQUIRED VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N')
```

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please print `row_data` and check if any item is a tuple.

Comment: row_data I am using currently :             row_data = [("appcode","appName","parent_app_code",datetime.datetime.now(),"insert",datetime.datetime.now(),"update_user","idfed_provider_id","idfed_SAML_gateway_URL","template","false","true","N","Y")]

Comment: You have a list with only one entry: a tuple. Now `execute` tries to fill in the whole tuple to parameter `:1`. Get rid of the list and use the tuple only or vice versa.

Comment: You can use `row_data[0]`. row_data should be a list or tuple of elements where individual element can not be a tuple/list itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using currently:
>
> ```py
> row_data = [("appcode","appName","parent_app_code",datetime.datetime.now(),"insert",datetime.datetime.now(),"update_user","idfed_provider_id","idfed_SAML_gateway_URL","template","false","true","N","Y")]
> ```

`row_data` is a list containing a tuple of 14 items. `curs.execute` is assigning the first element of the list to `:1`; however, that first element is the tuple which causes the error to be thrown.

As mentioned by [@Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909841/cx-oracle-notsupportederror-python-value-of-type-tuple-not-supported#comment104083848_58909841) you should remove either the `[]` list or the `()` tuple:

```py
row_data = ("appcode","appName","parent_app_code",datetime.datetime.now(),"insert",datetime.datetime.now(),"update_user","idfed_provider_id","idfed_SAML_gateway_URL","template","false","true","N","Y")
```

or

```py
row_data = ["appcode","appName","parent_app_code",datetime.datetime.now(),"insert",datetime.datetime.now(),"update_user","idfed_provider_id","idfed_SAML_gateway_URL","template","false","true","N","Y"]
```